# How to change cursor in a specific place?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

There are two images. One picture is surface mask. Two picture is background level. How to change cursor and use surface mask?

[image: platform] [image: mask]

The black square is the place of full motion. It has its own cursor.
The gray square is the place of partial motion. So it has its own cursor too.

I have got one idea.Create a buffer for the canvas and overlay the mask. But we will have to call GetPixelsColor everytime for mousemove. This decision is not rational.

Who was encounter similar? Thanks.

Comment: Your question should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have no example at the moment. I do not know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Then could you please clarify your question? I cannot understand it.

Comment: How do I change the cursor at a specific place in the game and use a surface map for it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
function draw(e) {
    changeCursor(canvas, e);
}

function changeCursor(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    coords = {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
    if(coords.x >= box.x && coords.x <= box.x+box.width && coords.y >= box.y && coords.y <= box.y+box.width){
        canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be much easier (and quicker) to just change the canvas cursor property. `canvas.style.cursor = "move";` Games and jQuery do not mix as jQuery is very slow.

Comment: But i draw on canvas (no used css).

Comment: Everything is OK now. :) Thanks for the example.

Comment: Can you replace box.x to a map of game surfaces (see images). May be GetColorPixel?

Comment: You may want to include the `else{canvas.style.cursor = 'default'}` too.

Comment: @Anonymous you'd be better using a data map rather than a raster one. Storing all pixels coords will eat memory unnecessarily.

Comment: @Kaiido, I agree, but i have got only raster map. :)

Comment: Then produce this data map before-hand, if all your shapes are squared it's quite easy.

Comment: @Kaiido, The figures can be any in the plans.